# How can i change spring boot backend port to 80 using docker compose?

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose

This is what my docker-compose looks like. I was using angular 4200 port and spring boot 8080 port during development. now i want to change backed port to 80 but when i do my frontend can not retrieve  data from backend anymore.

```
api:
    image: api-dev
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: api
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - data:/file-storage


  ui:
    image: ui-dev
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: ui
    ports:
      - 80:80
    environment:
      - API_URL=http://dev.website.com:8080
      - API_HOST=172.26.0.2
      - API_PORT=8080
    depends_on:
      - api


volumes:
   data:
```

proxy settings :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html = 404;
  }

  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://${HOST}:${PORT};
  }
}
```

Inside DockerFile :

```
ENV URL http://dev.website.com
ENV HOST 172.17.0.3
ENV PORT 80
### Copy Custom nginx conf

COPY ./docker-config/nginx-dev.conf /tmp/nginx-custom.conf
#COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# When the container starts, replace the env.js with values from environment variables
CMD ["/bin/sh",  "-c",  "envsubst '${HOST},${PORT}' < /tmp/nginx-custom.conf > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.template.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.js && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]

Thanks
```

Comment: can you check any other process is runing on port 80?

Comment: docker ps -> ui :  0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp

Answer (score 0):

To make the springboot listening on 80, you need set env `SERVER_PORT=80` for your api container.
But I think your Nginx proxy and Dockerfile is over complicated.
1, In my opinion you can keep api (springboot) on 8080, and change the nginx proxy config

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://api:8080;
  }
```

2, Hardcoded IP address is not necessary, may cause problem when you deploy the container to other Docker host. So you can remove all fixed IP address, the containers can communicate through internal DNS name (service name).

Comment: when i change port API_PORT to 80 frontend fails to retrieve data for some reason. Should i change every localhost:8080 url in my frontend i used to access api previously ?

Comment: You need figure out where is the `API_PORT` been used. If the variable name reflect it's use case correctly, it should equal to the SpringBoot listening port. In other word, if SpringBoot running on `8080`, then `API_PORT=8080`, so it depend on SpringBoot.